# how to Compile Consumer-Producer-ApI in Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, networking, g++, waf

I want to ./waf consumer-producer-api but it show some error CXXFLAGS error
and onChanged() error.
 please help me...

I use linux-mint and set up complete ndn-cxx and openssl

```
 $./waf configure
 Setting top to                           : /home/ndn/ntorrent/Consumer-
 Producer-API 
 Setting out to                           : /home/ndn/ntorrent/Consumer-
 Producer-API/build 
 Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
 Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++ 
 Checking for program 'doxygen'           : /usr/bin/doxygen 
 Checking for program 'tar'               : /bin/tar 
 Checking for program 'sphinx-build'      : /usr/bin/sphinx-build 
 **Checking supported CXXFLAGS              : -std=c++0x -std=c++11 -Wall -
 Wno-long-long -Wno-nested-anon-types -O2 -g** 
 Checking supported LINKFLAGS             :  
 Checking for program 'pkg-config'        : /usr/bin/pkg-config 
 Checking for 'libndn-cxx'                : yes 
 Checking boost includes                  : 1.58.0 
 Checking boost libs                      : ok 
 Checking for boost linkage               : ok 
'configure' finished successfully (4.485s)


$./waf
Waf: Entering directory `/home/ndn/ntorrent/build'
[ 1/12] Compiling src/file-manifest.cpp
../src/file-manifest.cpp: In member function ‘void 
ndn::ntorrent::FileManifest::encodeContent()’:
../src/file-manifest.cpp:240:13: error: ‘onChanged’ was not declared in this 
scope
   onChanged();
             ^
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-nested-anon-types’
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. According to the spirit and rules of the site, it is not meant to be a service where users solve issues on demand. To get help, please show the effort you've already made in solving the issue. See [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for further reference.

Comment: It looks like your gcc version does not like the -Wno-nested-anon-types ...